# Java How to convert a String into an List?

Tags: java, string, list

I have a String, which can have an multiple number of words which are dot separated.

`String s = "text.text1.text2.text3";`

I want to generate a List which adds a Element for each word in the String.

`List<String> list= Arrays.asList(s.split("/./"));` generates just 1 Element.

Is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

`String#split` is the way to go here, except that you want to split on the regex pattern `\.` by itself, as Java's regex API does not take delimiters:

```java
String s = "text.text1.text2.text3";
List<String> elements = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\."));
System.out.println(elements);  // [text, text1, text2, text3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the token is wrong, here is the correct code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SeperateString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "text.text1.text2.text3";
        List<String> list= Arrays.asList(s.split("\\."));
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
[text, text1, text2, text3]
```